# Dependencies issues when building dalvikvm on x86

Tags: android, compilation, dalvik, android-x86

I've been trying for the past few days to compile dalvikvm on x86 systems in order to only run Dalvik applications (no native, dalvikvm only) w/o all the throughput of dalvik-arm-qemu-emulate-x86, I fetched the whole src of android using repo sync and used the "android-4.2_r1" tag

after changing a few lines in dalvik/vm *mk's (making STATIC libs instead of dynamic ones, and add -j4 instead of -j2) I ran into what I think is a compilation dependency issue which I do not seem to manage to solve

```
  mm
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.0.1
TARGET_PRODUCT=full_x86
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=x86
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=x86-atom
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=ITL41D
============================================
make: Entering directory `/home/_test_x86/_test_x86/src__test_x86/src__test_x86'
make: *** No rule to make target `out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libcutils_intermediates/libcutils.a', needed by `out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libdvm_intermediates/libdvm.a'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory `/home/_test_x86/_test_x86/src__test_x86/src__test_x86'
```

when I try to do 'make clean' from the top of the tree and recompile it (mingling around the .mk's and changing different libs to be either static or dynamic) 
I get the same error only instead of libc it poses around libexpat or liblog

I'd appreciate if anyone could hint me how to solve it, as it seems like a cat-n-mouse race.

Comment: can anyone hint me ?:/